# GLOP - Google OR Tools - choose simplex method

Tags: c#, or-tools

I am using the default linear solver in GLOP (which I believe is dual-simplex) and getting `ABNORMAL` result.

I'd like to use normal simplex instead (as this post describes - https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1868) but I don't know how to change this setting.  How do I change the solver? (Using C# by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the parameters of the solver.

The class is here: http://google.github.io/or-tools/dotnet/classGoogle_1_1OrTools_1_1LinearSolver_1_1MPSolverParameters.html

You need to change the integer parameter http://google.github.io/or-tools/dotnet/classGoogle_1_1OrTools_1_1LinearSolver_1_1MPSolverParameters.html#a3b8427a9f4368fd831af8f8c61fb823c

The parameter to change is http://google.github.io/or-tools/dotnet/classGoogle_1_1OrTools_1_1LinearSolver_1_1MPSolverParameters.html#a7319655592ea63d50ef2a6645e309784

the value to assign is http://google.github.io/or-tools/dotnet/classGoogle_1_1OrTools_1_1LinearSolver_1_1MPSolverParameters.html#a79b59c0c868544afdaa05d89c8f8541f

Answer (score 2):

Laurent gives the correct steps above.  Here is the practical code to create these parameters and pass to solver (if anyone is interested):

```
var Params = new Google.OrTools.LinearSolver.MPSolverParameters();
Params.SetIntegerParam(MPSolverParameters.IntegerParam.LP_ALGORITHM, (int) MPSolverParameters.LpAlgorithmValues.PRIMAL);
Solver.ResultStatus solved = solver.Solve(Params);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the current documentation (see the last row of the table [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/lp_advanced#choice_of_solvers_and_algorithms)), it actually seems that the default mode is primal simplex, so that is what one would have if they did not set anything. You'd have to explicitly set parameters to make it work with dual simplex.