# LP model INFEASIBLE when expected Feasible

Tags: python, or-tools

I am using the default linear solver in GLOP with a problem that I know has an optimal solution, but it is terminating with INFEASIBLE when I use == in the constraints. I have looked at (https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/66039052/glop-google-or-tools-choose-simplex-method) and tried to set the tolerance parameter. I am not sure that I am setting it correctly or if it is not doing anything.

Here is python code that I am trying to execute

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
from ortools.glop.parameters_pb2 import GlopParameters


def solveRMP(patterns, orders):
    """ Solve the relaxed LP problem of minimizing sum(c*X_j) given the current patterns.

        Output: solution   - solution to the relaxed LP problem. ndarray of size(n)
    """
    n = len(patterns[0])
    num_patterns = len(patterns[1])

    #print(params)
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('GLOP')
#    solver.setSolverSpecificParametersAsString(operations_research.glop.Parameters.GlopParameters.newBuilder().setSolutionFeasibilityTolerance(1e-3).build().toString());

    if not solver:
        return -1

    constraint = []
    # Declare an array to hold our variables.
    X = [solver.NumVar(0.0, orders[i], f'x_{i}') for i in range(num_patterns)]

    cost = sum(X[j] for j in range(num_patterns))
    solver.Minimize(cost)

    # Create the constraints, one per row in patterns - sum(A_ij*X_j) == orders_i
    # Constraint requires type double, so need to cast to type double
    for i in range(n):
        constraint.append(solver.Add(sum(X[j] * patterns[i][j] for j in range(num_patterns)) ==
                                     orders[i]))

    status = solver.Solve()

    # Check that the problem has an optimal solution.
    if status != solver.OPTIMAL:
        print('The problem does not have an optimal solution!')
        if status == solver.FEASIBLE:
            print('A potentially suboptimal solution was found.')
        elif status == solver.INFEASIBLE:
            print('There is not a feasible solution')
        elif status == solver.ABNORMAL:
            print('The solver encountered a problem.')

    # Create array of solution values
    solution = [X[i].SolutionValue() for i in range(num_patterns)]

    dual = [constraint[i].DualValue() for i in range(n)]
    obj = solver.Objective().Value()

    return solution, dual, status, obj


orders = [20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 20, 18, 18, 14, 12, 25, 22]
demand = [2200, 2150, 2140, 2100, 2050, 2000, 1930, 1880, 1820, 1710, 1560, 1520, 1380]
capacity = [5600]

A = [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]


sol, dual, stat, obj = solveRMP(A, orders)
print(sol, dual ,obj, stat)
```

When the constraints are setup == then I get MPSolverInterface::result_status_ = MPSOLVER_INFEASIBLE When the constraints are setup >= then I get an answer [5.5, 6.0, 6.0, 3.6000000000000005, 12.0, 5.0, 3.7999999999999985, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 4.400000000000001, 7.0, 6.0]

I think there is an optimal solution in the case of the == constraints of [4.8, 5.3, 5.3, 3.6, 12.7, 5.0, 3.8, 7.0, 1.4, 9.0, 3.7, 7.0, 6.0]

I tried to set the tolerances with:

```
params = MPSolverParameters()
params.DUAL_TOLERANCE = 1e-3
params.PRIMAL_TOLERANCE = 1e-3
```

Then replace the solver.solve with

```
status = solver.Solve(params)
```

Is there something that I am setting up incorrectly either in the model or the MPSolverParameters?

Comment: Tried with Gurobi, still infeasible.

Comment: you can also try with clp. But most likely your proposed solution is not feasible.

Comment: Thanks all, indeed I tried also with MiniZinc and also got Infeasible.